# <mobilesdk> Customized SSO login page for Salesforce mobile SDK

Tags: ios, mobilesdk

We know that Salesforce offers a way to customize the SSO login page on Salesforce.com

(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/oauth_hide_gear_icon.htm).

We would like to introduce a 'native' screen developed for iOS mobile device to replace this SSO login page. How can we do silent authentication using iOS Mobile SDK? Can we pass on the credentials to the SDK which we capture through an external custom login view?

We would like to find out if this option is possible with Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

The example/doc you're referencing is a minor change of the login screen's UI (page layout), it's barely a customization.

If you go with your own, native screen you'll be able to use the SDK but you'll have to rewrite/rip out quite a bit of [authentication+authorization machinery](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/tree/master/libs/SalesforceSDKCore/SalesforceSDKCore/Classes/Security). There's very tight coupling between the login UI and the underlying security framework. Doable but very painful, the SDK wasn't engineered to be extended in the way you contemplate.